# Remove download button from odoo's pdf_viewer widget

Tags: javascript, python, widget, odoo, pdf-viewer

I'm trying to disable the download button located into the attachment preview widget of Odoo (Pdf_viewer) as you can see into the code below:

```
 <field name="preview" attrs="{'readonly': [('preview', '=', True)]}" widget="pdf_viewer" />
```

PS: I tried to set the field to readonly but still give for the reader the entire file.

[image]

I had a little help from a friend that suggested of changing the JS file containing the template of this button, but I don't know the steps to do that!
Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [_disableButtons](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/src/js/fields/basic_fields.js#L2143) function and hide the download button.

***Example***:

```
var basic_fields = require('web.basic_fields');

basic_fields.FieldPdfViewer.include({
    _disableButtons: function (iframe) {
        $(iframe).contents().find('button#download').hide();
        // $(iframe).contents().find('button#secondaryDownload').hide();
        this._super(iframe);
    },
});
```

If you need to control the download button visibility using the context attribute, try the following code:

```
var basic_fields = require('web.basic_fields');
var Context = require('web.Context');

basic_fields.FieldPdfViewer.include({
    _disableButtons: function (iframe) {
        var self = this;
        if (self.attrs.context) {
            var context = new Context(self.attrs.context).eval();
            if(!context.download) {
                $(iframe).contents().find('button#download').hide();
                // $(iframe).contents().find('button#secondaryDownload').hide();
            }
        }
        this._super(iframe);
    },
});
```

***Edit:***

Create an XML file with the following content and add it to the `data` entry in the manifest file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" inherit_id="web.assets_backend" name="assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript"
                        src="/module_name/static/src/js/pdf_viewser.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Create `pdf_viewser.js` under `static/src/js` and add the above code:

```js
odoo.define('module_name.PDFViewer', function (require) {
    "use strict";
    
    var basic_fields = require('web.basic_fields');

    basic_fields.FieldPdfViewer.include({
        _disableButtons: function (iframe) {
            $(iframe).contents().find('button#download').hide();
            // $(iframe).contents().find('button#secondaryDownload').hide();
            this._super(iframe);
        },
    });

});
```

The steps are listed in the [Adding files in an asset bundle](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#adding-files-in-an-asset-bundle) section. For more details check the [Assets Management](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#assets-management) documentation.

Comment: Great thanks @kenly, i just add the line into the existed _disableButtons function like so:  _disableButtons: `function (iframe) {
        $(iframe).contents().find('button#openFile').hide();
        $(iframe).contents().find('button#download').hide();
    },` and it work the question is if i want to use overide methode should i put your code under the `var FieldPdfViewer = FieldBinaryFile.e..` or out side the cote?

Comment: Do you want to apply  your modifications without editing the original file?

Comment: yes, like it is shown ih this link : [How to extend / add new widget in chrome in pos](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/how-to-inherit-js-file-in-odoo-113575)

Comment: Check my edit. I also added a link to the official documentation.