# Remove download button from odoo's pdf_viewer main widget

Tags: javascript, widget, odoo, odoo-15, pdf-viewer

I found this answer and it helps to remove the download button from field's widget, but how can I do this with the main widget? I mean, the one that appears when you click on records' attachments.
[Remove download button from odoo's pdf_viewer widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386265/remove-download-button-from-odoos-pdf-viewer-widget)

Also I'm reading this about "Modifying a main widget from the interface" but I don't find the way  to do this with the main widget https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/frontend/javascript_cheatsheet.html

[Main widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBzl4.png)

I tried with this code but it wont' help, only on the fields widget. At least that's what I see.

```
var basic_fields = require('web.basic_fields');
basic_fields.FieldPdfViewer.include({
    _disableButtons: function (iframe) {
        $(iframe).contents().find('button#download').hide();
        // $(iframe).contents().find('button#secondaryDownload').hide();
        this._super(iframe);
    },
});`
```